# Inflate a Viewstub that contains a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewstub

Is there any problems when inflating a viewstub that contains a fragment. In crashalytics I am rarely seeing

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException
Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
```

Caused by

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

The action is being triggered by an onclick, as shown below.

```
public void openPlayer() {
    if (mSlidingLayout != null) {
        if (mSlidingLayout.findViewById(R.id.viewer_stub) != null) {
            ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) mSlidingLayout.findViewById(R.id.viewer_stub);
            stub.inflate();
        }
        mSlidingLayout.expandPanel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Recently I came across the same question and put it to the test.

A fragment inside a ViewStub **does** work.

The only difference is that the Fragment will start its lifecycle when the inflate() method is called upon the ViewStub.

---

Your problem is within the fragment content.

Just to test I've created a Fragment that goes inside a ViewStub and throwed a RTE when the views were about to be created.

```
public class UserSetupFragment extends Fragment {


   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       System.out.println("Create View");
       throw new RuntimeException("Test");
   }

}
```

On the console I receive the following Exception:

```
01-02 06:48:19.260: E/AndroidRuntime(31533): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
```

As you can see, if anything crashes before your view is successfuly returned, you will receive a InflateException.

You should debug inside the fragments class, or post its code.

Comment: This issue seems to happen 0.001% of the time in the wild. I suspect it may be related to inflate not happening instantly but I'm still not sure. Thanks for the info, very interesting.